# Extracting data from formatted plain text in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert some basic, formatted, plain text into a PHP array, so I can then further manipulate and display the data.

Below is an anonymized dataset of what I'm working with...

```
|    |Customer                   |From |To   |Bkg |Cabin |Class |Seat |Accept    | 
|1   |Palmer Lee Mr              |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |3K   |          | 
|2   |Palmer Jamiee J Mrs        |JFK  |LAX  |Y   |P     |P     |3F   |Boarded   | 
|3   |Coleman David Mr           |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |2F   |Boarded   | 
|4   |Coleman Roberta Mrs        |JFK  |LAX  |Y   |P     |A     |2K   |          | 
|5   |Williams Marina Lady       |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |F     |1K   |          | 
|6   |Graham Christine A Mrs     |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |4F   |          | 
|7   |Graham Dean A Mr           |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |4A   |          | 
|8   |Howell Fiona Ms            |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |5K   |          | 
|9   |Cobb Hamish Mr             |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |1A   |          | 
|10  |Brown Derek Mr             |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |2A   |Accepted  | 
|11  |Brown Elizabeth Mrs        |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |3A   |Accepted  | 
|12  |Reyes Ciaran Mrs           |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |F     |5A   |Standby   | 
|13  |Reyes Joseph Mr            |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |F     |5F   |Standby   |
```

I have attempted to use `substr();` and `preg_replace();` but with no luck.

Does anyone have any experience in data manipulation like this? Would love some assistance!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: You can also use the CSV functions, and tell it that `|` is the field delimiter.

Comment: is that how your plain text looks like or have you made like a table to make others understand.

Comment: @Ramyz that's exactly how the data is formatted, spaces and all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$text = "|    |Customer                   |From |To   |Bkg |Cabin |Class |Seat |Accept    | 
|1   |Palmer Lee Mr              |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |3K   |          | 
|2   |Palmer Jamiee J Mrs        |JFK  |LAX  |Y   |P     |P     |3F   |Boarded   | 
|3   |Coleman David Mr           |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |2F   |Boarded   | 
|4   |Coleman Roberta Mrs        |JFK  |LAX  |Y   |P     |A     |2K   |          | 
|5   |Williams Marina Lady       |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |F     |1K   |          | 
|6   |Graham Christine A Mrs     |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |4F   |          | 
|7   |Graham Dean A Mr           |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |4A   |          | 
|8   |Howell Fiona Ms            |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |5K   |          | 
|9   |Cobb Hamish Mr             |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |A     |1A   |          | 
|10  |Brown Derek Mr             |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |2A   |Accepted  | 
|11  |Brown Elizabeth Mrs        |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |P     |3A   |Accepted  | 
|12  |Reyes Ciaran Mrs           |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |F     |5A   |Standby   | 
|13  |Reyes Joseph Mr            |JFK  |LAX  |    |P     |F     |5F   |Standby   |";

    //gets each line in a array
    $pieces1 = explode("\n", $text);

    // now create a loop if u want with array length and get each line and explode it again 
    // OR just callto any line by $pieces1[number]
    $pieces2 = explode("|", $pieces1[3]);
    // Remove first and last blank elements
    $result = array_slice($pieces2, 1, -1);
?>

// print_r($result)
        Array
    (
        [0] => 3   
        [1] => Coleman David Mr           
        [2] => JFK  
        [3] => LAX  
        [4] =>     
        [5] => P     
        [6] => A     
        [7] => 2F   
        [8] => Boarded   
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use fgetcsv function and set the | as the separator for example:

```
?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```